# Compare ID's on two different rows and run code

Tags: excel, vba

I've written a macro to run a new order, based on an old one.
In the first column I am able to select "old" or "new", where the "old" reference will be used for the new one.
But as a cross-check I want to check if the ID's are the same, if not, it should stop the macro.

The table as an illustration:

| Create | ID | reference | Date1 | Date2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ***Old*** | ABCD | 123456 | "empty" | 01/01/2023 |
| random | random | random | random | random |
| random | random | random | random | random |
| ***New*** | ABCD | "empty" | 01/06/2023 | "empty" |

The code that I tried to make, but didn't succeed:

```
intValueToFind = "Old"
       For a = 2 To Rows
        If Cells(a, 1).Value = intValueToFind Then
        Old_ID = Cells(a, 2).Value
        Else
        MsgBox ("Select an old order")
        Exit Sub
        End If
       Next a
        
intValueToFind = "New"
       For b = 2 To Rows
        If Cells(b, 1).Value = intValueToFind Then
        New_ID = Cells(b, 2).Value
        Else
        MsgBox ("Select a new order")
        Exit Sub
        End If

        If Old_ID = New_ID Then
          GoTo Create_order
        Else
          MsgBox ("The ID's don't match")
        Exit Sub
        End If
       Next b 
Create_order:
```

It should also be possible to have 1 row selected as "old" and multiple as "new". Is it possible to loop this check as well?

Comment: So for each combination of `"Old" & (some id)` you want to check if there is any row that contais same id but with *New* instead of *old*, right? Something like `"New" & (some id)`

Answer (score 1):

Based on my comment I think you need something like this:

```
Sub test()
Dim i As Long
Dim LR As Long
Dim MyF As WorksheetFunction
Set MyF = WorksheetFunction

'get last used row in column A
LR = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To LR Step 1
    If Range("A" & i).Value = "Old" Then
        'Check if there is any new somewhere
        If MyF.CountIfs(Range("A2:A" & LR), "New", Range("B2:B" & LR), Range("B" & i).Value) > 0 Then
            'match, do something
        Else
            'no match, do nothing or another diferent thing
        End If
    End If
Next i

Set MyF = Nothing
End Sub
```

The code will loop trough column A. If the value `Old` is found, it will count how many cells of `New` with same ID exists. If the count is greater than zero then proceed as you need (locate the row or do whatever you need) else do nothing.